# Sine Wave Plotting

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, plot, trigonometry

I am trying to generate a sin wave which gets chopped regularly in a time interval of 0.004 second (the output will be a sin wave at time 0 to 0.004 seconds and then output is zero at time 0.004 second to 0.008 second.This will continue in a similar manner).

I tried the following code but it doesn't generate the correct output.

```
f=10000000000;
k=0;
for i=0:0.004:1
    k=k+1;
    if(mod(k,2)~=0)
        t=i:0.001:i+0.004;
        y=sin(2*3.14*f*t);
        plot(t,y);
    else
        t=i:0.001:i+0.004;
        y=0;
        plot(t,y);
    end
end
```

Comment: A bit more description on the output you want might be helpful: what portion do you want chopped?

Comment: i have edited my description.

Answer (score 0):

For plotting in Matlab, you want an array of x values, and a corresponding array of y values for the entire section you want to plot. So you want to first create an x array corresponding to the time from 0 to 1.004 (if I understand your code correctly), and create a y array *of the same length*, and populate it with the corresponding sine and 0 values.

```
f = 10000000000;
% generate evenly spaced x axis of 251*n+1 points evenly spaced between 0 and 1.004 (i.e. spacing between two points is 0.004/n). n should be an integer.
t = linspace(0, 1.004, 251*n+1);
% generate unchopped sine
y = sin(2*3.14*f*t);
% set desired intervals to zero
for i=1:251*n+1 % for each index in y
    % if the corresponding entry in t is a multiple of 0.008, backfill y with zeros for 0.004s.
    if(mod(t(i), 0.008)==0)
        if(i>1-n)
            for j=i-n:i
                y(j) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
end
plot(t, y)
```

Comment: i tried your code,but it resulted in error.It says attempt to access y(3.984),index must be a positive integer or logical

Comment: @Ishant Tiwari, my previous approach did not work with general n, I edited so now it should work with positive integer n. We're trying to access the indices of y that correspond to the sections between 0.004 and 0.008 for example, and indices work like counting, so these have to be positive integers.